# Amazon RDS - Postgresql role cannot access tables

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, roles

created a postgresql instance on AWS with the username ziggy. I restored a database to that instance. however I cannot even select any of the tables

```
select * FROM mac_childcare_parcels
```

gives me `ERROR:  permission denied for relation mac_childcare_parcels
********** Error **********`

the owner of that table belongs to the postgres login.

so i tried running this: `grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to ziggy` but since I am not a superuser I cannot give myself privileges so that throws a permissions error. what do I have to do to get access to the tables?

this does not work either

`grant select on mac_childcare_parcels to ziggy`

this query returns successful but does not let the login ziggy access the tables

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO ziggy;
```

Comment: You won't get a good answer unless you tell us how exactly you restored the database (with which database user). Also, you should say what `\dp mac_childcare_parcels` gives you in `psql`.

Comment: i used pgadmin -- pointed to the backup file and restored it without touching any options

Comment: Ok, this needs the following information: `SELECT current_user, n.nspname, c.relacl, n.nspacl FROM pg_class AS c JOIN pg_namespace AS n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid WHERE relname = 'mac_childcare_parcels';`

Answer (score 2):

First login with superuser and provide all rds superuser access to the newly created user using a command like below

```
GRANT rds_superuser TO ziggy;
```

replace **rds_superuser** with your rds superuser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also GRANT USAGE on the SCHEMA, e.g.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO ziggy;
```

Comment: i did this query -- which returned succesfullly but I still cannot select any of the tables

Answer (score 0):

The superuser access is needed to run the access level queries. But as you said that access is not present then i would say copy the replica of the db which you have restored from backup and grant yourself as superuser. 
then provide all needed access to any users.

Comment: do you mean on my local copy, create a username ziggy and make that a superuser. back it up, then restore it to the AWS server?